# The Faerie Army is coming!

Tags: chess, game

Well, we're all in trouble, yet again. The fabled Faerie Army has come to take over our dimension.

This is the battlefield:

[image]

However, their soldiers don't work quite like ours...

> Their **pawns** move as ours, but they capture the same way (one space in front of them). They can't capture with a two-space move. Due to some ancient curse, they can't move a pawn three turns in a row (whether the same pawn, or three different ones)
>
> Their **knights** move as a knight, but they make multiple knight moves in the same direction. They jump over anything in their path, but **they can't stop** (they must go until they literally can't because of the edge of the board.) They capture only if they land on a piece on the last square they would move to.
>
> Their **bishops** can only move an even number of squares.
>
> Their **rooks** move like our rooks but capture as our bishops.
>
> Their **queen** moves like our queen but captures like our knights.
>
> Their **king** moves like our knights, but can't capture. We have to checkmate the king to win.

Oh hey, they just made their first move.

[image]

Well, over to you. Can you win or at least draw?

(Yes, you must assume the worst.)

Comment: the fairy pawns "can't" move 3 times in a row?

Comment: @Jannis yes... not exactly sure what you're asking though, is the wording confusing?

Comment: Yes this is quite confusing since I'd never expect a pawn to move 3 times.

Comment: @Jannis changed from 3 times to 3 turns, maybe that's clearer?

Comment: Do you know that this puzzle *has* a solution that can be figured out reasonably? It seems like your Conway's Game of Life chess puzzle had implications that weren't thought through, and I'm worried that this will be unsolvable without significant computer power.

Comment: @Deusovi I believe I have a solution to this.

Comment: can the fairy knight kill all figures on his way to the end of the board?

Comment: Can a knight move from h3 to f2 if d1 is blocked by a white piece? Or is it an illegal move?

Comment: @jafe that would be illegal

Answer (score 2):

So ...

> It's possible to mate with 2 turns
>  [image: twoturns]

What happens:

> NXe7 QXe7
>  NXd7 QXe2#

Because:

> King can't escape,
>  queen can only hit like a knight
>   and bishop cant go 2 fields

Earlier Edit:

> [image: like this]
>  NXe7 QXe7
>  Kf3 Qe6
>  Kh4 Qg4#

Comment: 1. It's not a helpmate, and 2. If it were a helpmate, there's a way to do it quicker. Nice try, though!

Comment: @ExcitedRaichu Why it isn't?

Comment: because there's a way to do it without helping

Comment: What do you mean with 'helping'? Why wouldn't this be checkmate?

Comment: Assume the faerie army is trying to win. I can state this more bluntly in the question if you'd like.

Comment: lol just seeing, nice man :)

Comment: @ExcitedRaichu I've Edited, Is it correct now?

Comment: Yep, that's the quickest possible, but what about 2. e3?

Comment: @ExcitedRaichu well then protects the queen the pawn and the knight would protect the field behind

Comment: I think you're close...

Comment: e3 is useless but consider b2.

Comment: @ExcitedRaichu how is Qxe7 possible? I thought queen captures as knights?

Answer (score 1):

White's pieces are incredibly weak and Black is sure to win. However, I can't see any directly forcing lines, so here's some notes on basic openings:

> To generalize the other answer, after 1. ...Qxe7, moving the other knight, or any pawn other than those on the c, e, and g, files is mate after 2. ...Qxe2#. 2. e4 is likewise mate, 2. Kd3?? is mated by ...Qe4# (3. xe4 is not possible), and 2. Kf3's only continuations after ...Qe4+ are 3. Ke1 Qxe2# or 3. Kg5 f6+ 4. Kh3 (d5,d6,Qf5,Qg4,or Qh4)#.
>  Moving the c or g pawns is a disaster for White - while Black cannot immediately force mate, since 2. (c3/g3) Qxe2+ 3. (Kc2/Kg2) Qe4+ 4. (Bd3/Qf3) and now Black must either develop further or gradually erode White's defenses before continuing further - a better option is to immediately take White's queen and mop up the rest of the back rank before the pawns can get out of the way.
>  This leaves the question of **2. e3.** While the position is likely still winnable for Black even after a bad trade on e3 (either with the queen directly or with the dark-square bishop, in which case White will likely support with d3), doing so will involve a long and drawn-out battle as most of the back ranks are still locked in place. A better move for Black is **2. ...Qe5,** opening the dark-square bishop and attacking the h-pawn, which can't be defended with 3. Qf3 since that allows 3. ...Qxe3+ 4. Qe2 Qxe2#.
>  White's only hope is a line like 3. Na4 Qxh2 4. Rg1 Qxg2 5. Bd3 (Bb5 gives the king an escape square but is easily routed), and any attempt from Black to dislodge the position by pushing pawns on the queenside is too slow to prevent 6. Rf1.
>  This just means that Black should sidestep with 5. ...Qg4, with 6. Qf3 Qxa4 7. Rb1 being the only line that doesn't immediately result in back rank collapse. Where from there? White's weak material has found a decently strong fortress that Black's queen can't quite crack by itself - the quickest lines probably start 7. ...Ba3.